# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin error in jquery request

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am trying to access a different web content and get the contents from the web content to another web. 
i get above title error all the time in my jquery request.

here is my code

```
 $.ajax({
 url: 'destinationURL',
 type: "POST", //This is what you should chage
 dataType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
 username: "FAA/uttam ctr dhakal", // Most SAP web services require credentials
 password: "MEETfamily2018",
 processData: false,
 contentType: "application/json",
 headers: {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "(TRIED WITH Destination/Source 
 Both URLs)",
  },
 success: function () {
     alert("success");
 },
  error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { //Add these parameters to 
  display the required response
     alert(xhr.status);
     alert(xhr.responseText);
 },
});
```

Comment: Plese try searching before asking. There are 100's of similar questions https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=No+%27Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: did you mean getting content from another site via jQuery AJAX?

Answer (score 0):

That happens when the destination has no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' set on response headers allowing you web site or `*` for any web site.